# Can every algebraic variety of dimension $n$ be covered by $n+1$ affine opens?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a complete algebraic variety of dimension $n$. Must there exist an affine covering with $n+1$ pieces?

(For a projective variety in $\mathbf{P}^m$, we can always project it to some subspace $\mathbf{P}^n$ with $n$ equals the dimension of X, by a composition of projection from points.  Since projection is affine morphism, we are done. For complete varieties, we have Chow lemma, thus $X$ is dominated by some projective variety, but can we find a such a covering or not?)

Comment: Isn't this proposition 3.6 in these notes by A. Bertram: http://www.math.utah.edu/~bertram/6030/Affine.pdf

Comment: @IgorRivin I don't see the connection...

Comment: @Ycor Isn't the connection in the following corollary (3.7)?

Comment: @IgorRivin the corollary says "Every quasi-affine variety has an open cover by quasi-affine
varieties that are isomorphic to affine varieties." It does not say anything about the number... and anyway it only works with quasi-affine varieties.

Comment: @mqx What do you mean by "varieties in $P^m$"? if you mean quasi-projective varieties occurring in $P^m$ the obvious argument yields a covering by quasi-affine varieties (and by the way I don't understand your projection argument).

Comment: @YCor The number $n+1$ seems to be immediate from the argument (though, of course, I might be missing something).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. Example 4.9 of [Roth and Vakil](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0406384) shows that, for any $m$, there is a singular, integral complete $3$-fold which cannot be covered by $m$ open affines. The authors mention as an open problem whether there is a smooth example. If you don't require varieties to be integral, Example 4.8 gives a simpler construction, which the authors credit to Jason Starr.

There was also some discussion in comments about whether this is true for projective or quasi-projective varieties. The answer is yes in both cases. See the proof of Theorem 18.2.6 in [Vakil's textbook](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGapr2915public.pdf) for the projective case, and the discussion in Section 22.4.15 for the quasi-projective case.

Comment: The projective case is trivial: $P^m$ is a union of $m+1$ affine open subsets, and hence so is any closed subset of $P^m$.

Comment: @YCor The question is if $X$ is a closed $m$ dimensional subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^n$, with $n>m$, is $X$ a union of $m+1$ affines. The answer is yes (see the proof in Vakil), and it isn't hard, but it is less trivial than that.